# unsigned char* causes Access Violation Exception

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, access-violation

I am developing a wrapper library that allow my project using a x86 C++ dll library in any CPU environment, I have no control about the dll thus I am using DllImport in C#.

There is a provided function which declared in C++: int __stdcall Func(int V, unsigned char *A)
and provided a sample declaration in VB: Private Declare Function Func Lib "lib.dll" Alias "_Func@8" (ByVal V As Long, A As Any) As Long

This function will request a device to Add/Deduct a value to/from a card by passing Convert.ToInt64(decimalValue) as V, and some customize information in A.

Here is the description of A:

- It is a byte pointer containing 7 bytes.
- The first 5 bytes are used to stores info that will be passed to the card log (The last 4 digits of the receipt number should be included in the first 2 bytes, the other 3 could be A3A4A5)
- The last 2 bytes are used to stores info that will be passed to the device (The last 4 digits of the receipt number)
- On return, the A contains a 32 bytes data.

After hours and hours of researches and tries, I cannot make result other than 'Access Violation Exception'. Please see the following draft code:

```
[DllImport("lib.dll", EntryPoint="_Func@8")]
public static external Int64 Func(Int64 V, StringBuilder sb);

string ReceiptNum = "ABC1234";
decimal Amount = 10m;
byte[] A = new byte[32];
A[0] = Convert.ToByte(ReceiptNum.Substring(3, 2));
A[1] = Convert.ToByte(ReceiptNum.Substring(5));
A[2] = Convert.ToByte("A3");
A[3] = Convert.ToByte("A4");
A[4] = Convert.ToByte("A5");
A[5] = Convert.ToByte(ReceiptNum.Substring(3, 2));
A[6] = Convert.ToByte(ReceiptNum.Substring(5));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
    new ASCIIEncoding().GetString(A), A.Length
);
Int64 Result = Func(Convert.ToInt64(Amount), sb);
```

And at this point it throws the exception. I have tried passing IntPtr, byte*, byte (by A[0]), byval, byref and none of them works. (Tried to deploy as x86 CPU as well)

Would appreciate any help! Thanks for your time!

---

PS - The reason of using StringBuilder is the library contains a function that accept a "char *Data" parameter that causes the same exception, and the solution is using StringBuilder to pass as a pointer, this function's VB Declaration is: Private Declare Function Func1 Lib "lib.dll" Alias "_Func1@12(ByVal c As Byte, ByVal o As Byte, ByVal Data As String) As Long

Comment: Keep in mind that the `ASCIIEncoding` only supports 7-bit characters, so it's not going to return hex values `0xA3`, `0xA4` or `0xA5`.  Also `Convert.ToByte(string)` only handles decimal digits 0-9; `Convert.ToByte("A3")` will throw a FormatException. So I'm not sure how you're even getting to call `Func()`.

Comment: Hi Michael! Since I cannot connect to my office development server right now, so I just wrote the code from memory, would try Luaan solution tmr:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your native method signature takes `int`, and you're trying to pass a `long long`. That's not going to work, rather obviously. The same is true with the return value. Don't assume that VB maps clearly to VB.NET, much less C# - `Long` means a 32-bit integer in VB, but not in .NET. Native code is a very complex environment, and you better know what you're doing when trying to interface with native.

`StringBuilder` should only be used for character data. That's not your case, and you should use `byte[]` instead. No matter the fun things you're doing, you're trying to pass invalid unicode data instead of raw bytes. The confusion is probably from the fact that C doesn't distinguish between `byte[]` and `string` - both are usually represented as `char*`.

Additionally, I don't see how you'd expect this wrapper to work in an AnyCPU environment. If the native DLL is 32-bit, you can only use it from a 32-bit process. AnyCPU isn't magic, it just defers the decision of bit-ness to runtime, rather than compile-time.

Comment: Hi Luaan, really thanks for your help! I have done a quick research and just find out Long in VB means Int32, so I guess I have to use Int32 for all variables marked as int in C++, right? And since VB treat ByRef as default param passing method, I should add ref to the external function as well. I have no device on hand so please allow me get back to you ASAP, thanks again!

Comment: @ZayLau It's more complicated than that, but I think you can safely ignore the differences nowadays - assuming `int` maps to `int` should work well enough. Note that the first argument is passed `ByVal` in VB anyway, so no `ref`. The second argument will be marshalled, and it's an array, not a pointer to an array, so again, no `ref`..

Comment: @ZayLau: "Long" was 32 bits in VB6.  In modern versions of VB, it is 64 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Your external definition is wrong.

StringBuilder is a complex structure containing an array of c# char.

c# chars are utf-16 (double bytes with complex rules for decoding unicode multichar caracters). Probably not what your are seeking.

If your data is a raw byte bufer you should go for byte[]

Int64 is also c# long.